# ASP.NET check which button was clicked

Tags: c#, asp.net

Here's the deal, I making a website that sells some products and according to how much products I have the ammount of buttons changes too.

For example if I have 5 products I will have 5 buttons, something like this: 
[image: Example]

What I want to do is when a button is clicked I want to take the item name and save it (in a session) so I can use this information on a different page (the code behind is in C#).

How can I do this?

Html:

```
<div runat="server" id="CatalogProducts" class="container-fluid">


</div>
```

Code behind:

```
        SqlHey SQLViewProducts = new SqlHey();
        DataSet DSViewProducts = new DataSet();
        string Sheilta = "SELECT TblShop.ItemName, TblShop.Price, TblShop.ShopType, TblShop.Image, TblShop.Description FROM TblShop;";
        DSViewProducts = SQLViewProducts.chkData(Sheilta);
        int I;
        for (I = 0; I < DSViewProducts.Tables[0].Rows.Count; I++)
        {
            if (DSViewProducts.Tables[0].Rows.Count % 2 == 0)
            {
                if (I % 2 == 0)
                    CatalogProducts.InnerHtml += " <div class=\"row\"> <div style=\"position: relative\" class=\"col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 col-sm-push-1 animated bounceInLeft\"> <div class=\"hovereffect\"> <img class=\"img-responsive\" src= \".." + DSViewProducts.Tables[0].Rows[I][3].ToString() + "\"" + " alt=\"\"> <div class=\"overlay\"> <h2>הוסף<span style=\"font-size: 0.65em\"></span> <asp:Button ID=\"Button1\" runat=\"server\" BackColor=\"Transparent\" BorderStyle=\"None\" ForeColor=\"Transparent\" Height=\"43px\" Style=Height=\"z-index: 99; left: 0px; position: absolute; top: 0px\" Text=\"a\" Width=\"87px\" />לסל</h2> <p class=\"icon-links\">" + DSViewProducts.Tables[0].Rows[I][0].ToString() + "<br /> " + DSViewProducts.Tables[0].Rows[I][4].ToString() + " </p> </div> </div> </div>";
                else CatalogProducts.InnerHtml += " <div style=\"position: relative\" class=\"col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 col-sm-push-1 animated bounceInLeft\"> <div class=\"hovereffect\"> <img class=\"img-responsive\" src= \".." + DSViewProducts.Tables[0].Rows[I][3].ToString() + "\"" + " alt=\"\"> <div class=\"overlay\"> <h2>הוסף<span style=\"font-size: 0.65em\"></span> <asp:Button ID=\"Button1\" runat=\"server\" BackColor=\"Transparent\" BorderStyle=\"None\" ForeColor=\"Transparent\" Height=\"43px\" Style=Height=\"z-index: 99; left: 0px; position: absolute; top: 0px\" Text=\"a\" Width=\"87px\" />לסל</h2> <p class=\"icon-links\">" + DSViewProducts.Tables[0].Rows[I][0].ToString() + "<br /> " + DSViewProducts.Tables[0].Rows[I][4].ToString() + " </p> </div> </div> </div> </div> <br /> <br />";
            }

            if (DSViewProducts.Tables[0].Rows.Count % 2 != 0)
            {
                if (I + 1 == DSViewProducts.Tables[0].Rows.Count)
                    CatalogProducts.InnerHtml += " <div class=\"row\"> <div style=\"position: relative\" class=\"col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 col-sm-push-1 animated bounceInLeft\"> <div class=\"hovereffect\"> <img class=\"img-responsive\" src= \".." + DSViewProducts.Tables[0].Rows[I][3].ToString() + "\"" + " alt=\"\"> <div class=\"overlay\"> <h2>הוסף לסל</h2> <p class=\"icon-links\">" + DSViewProducts.Tables[0].Rows[I][0].ToString() + "<br /> " + DSViewProducts.Tables[0].Rows[I][4].ToString() + " </p> </div> </div> </div>";
                if (I % 2 == 0)
                    CatalogProducts.InnerHtml += " <div class=\"row\"> <div style=\"position: relative\" class=\"col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 col-sm-push-1 animated bounceInLeft\"> <div class=\"hovereffect\"> <img class=\"img-responsive\" src= \".." + DSViewProducts.Tables[0].Rows[I][3].ToString() + "\"" + " alt=\"\"> <div class=\"overlay\"> <h2>הוסף<span style=\"font-size: 0.65em\"></span> <asp:Button ID=\"Button1\" runat=\"server\" BackColor=\"Transparent\" BorderStyle=\"None\" ForeColor=\"Transparent\" Height=\"43px\" Style=Height=\"z-index: 99; left: 0px; position: absolute; top: 0px\" Text=\"a\" Width=\"87px\" />לסל</h2> <p class=\"icon-links\">" + DSViewProducts.Tables[0].Rows[I][0].ToString() + "<br /> " + DSViewProducts.Tables[0].Rows[I][4].ToString() + " </p> </div> </div> </div> </div> <br /> <br />";
                else CatalogProducts.InnerHtml += " <div style=\"position: relative\" class=\"col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 col-sm-push-1 animated bounceInLeft\"> <div class=\"hovereffect\"> <img class=\"img-responsive\" src= \".." + DSViewProducts.Tables[0].Rows[I][3].ToString() + "\"" + " alt=\"\"> <div class=\"overlay\"> <h2>הוסף<span style=\"font-size: 0.65em\"></span> <asp:Button ID=\"Button1\" runat=\"server\" BackColor=\"Transparent\" BorderStyle=\"None\" ForeColor=\"Transparent\" Height=\"43px\" Style=Height=\"z-index: 99; left: 0px; position: absolute; top: 0px\" Text=\"a\" Width=\"87px\" />לסל</h2> <p class=\"icon-links\">" + DSViewProducts.Tables[0].Rows[I][0].ToString() + "<br /> " + DSViewProducts.Tables[0].Rows[I][4].ToString() + " </p> </div> </div> </div> </div> <br /> <br />";
            }
        }
```

The methood chkData:

```
public DataSet chkData(string sqlstr)
{



        string path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/");
        string fileName = "Hey.mdb";
        path += fileName;
        string connString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data source=" + path;
        OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connString);


        OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(sqlstr, conn);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
        return ds;
}
```

Comment: Are you using repeater..?

Comment: How do you create your buttons? show us the code

Comment: @Arvin I added the code.

Comment: @AkashAmin I added the code.

Comment: all buttons have same id's and same text , how can one differentiate buttons

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use `Repeater` for this solution. Check out [this link](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/c59e94/how-to-fire-button-click-event-in-repeater-control-in-asp-ne/). It will tell you what to do step by step.

Comment: How can I make the Repeater to make my div as I did?

Comment: @harel486 if you mean doing seperate things for even and odd Items, you can use <ItemTemplate> and <AlternatingItemTemplate> tags inside Repeater

Answer (score 0):

In the CatalogProducts.InnerHtml bind the for loop count to button ID,if not possible to bind then try instead of asp button you may use input type="button"

I just added to your code refer this..

```
<input type="Button" id=\"Button_\"+I />
```